# Shopify customer list and Mailchimp

Tags: shopify, mailchimp

Is it possible to create a sign up form that sends the customer's details (email address, name, etc.) to both my Mailchimp account's mailing list and my Shopify store's customer list upon submission?

Answer (score 0):

This [app](https://apps.shopify.com/chimpified) lets you add your customers(who sign up for marketing) automatically to the mailchimp list. You can add a field in the form which will add all users to the marketing list of shopify and then automatically to the mailchimp list.

Answer (score -1):

You can find information about creating Customers to Shopify in their API:

[Creating a new customer](https://docs.shopify.com/api/customer#create)

You can also find information in how to add a member to a list in MailChimp's API:

[Adding a new member to a list](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/members/lists-members-collection)